# How to keep time-varying but entity-invariant variables in a panel regression fixed effects model?

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, macroeconomics

I am working with a panel dataset that spans 2000Q1 to 2020Q3 and captures quarterly capital flows to 35 different Emerging Market Economies (EMEs). Along with the capital flows data, I have several control variables:

1. Country-specific variables for each EME (e.g., Interest rate differentials vis-a-vis the US, GDP growth rate differentials vis-a-vis the US, and Changes in exchange rate against USD). These country-specific variables are time-varying and entity-varying variables.
2. A global risk appetite measure, represented by the VIX index. This variable is time-varying but remains constant across all EMEs for a given quarter (e.g., if in 2000Q3 the VIX is 5%, all EMEs in the dataset have a VIX value of 5% for that quarter).

My goal is to employ a fixed effects regression model where I regress capital flows on the aforementioned control variables. My concern is that when I include both entity and time fixed effects, the VIX gets dropped due to perfect collinearity with the time fixed effects, given its cross-sectionally constant nature.

I tried to incorporate VIX with other variables (e.g., some country-specific variables or country code), and the result is a bit hard to interpret and might not be easy for audience to follow.

However, upon reviewing related literature, I've observed that many studies retain the VIX (instead of interaction of something else with VIX) in their fixed effects empirical models. I'm curious as to how this is achieved.

Any guidance on incorporating time-varying but entity-invariant (the VIX in my case) into a fixed effects model without it being dropped would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: What's motivating your choice of the VIX? Some precedent in the literature on which you're building your model? It's hardly a measure of *global risk appetite*, don't you think? "VIX is the ticker symbol and the popular name for the Chicago Board Options Exchange's CBOE Volatility Index, a popular measure of the stock market's expectation of volatility based on S&P 500 index options. It is calculated and disseminated on a real-time basis by the CBOE, and is often referred to as the fear index or fear gauge." There must be better metrics e.g., search 'global market risk' for suggestions

Comment: Here's one alternative approach *Determinants of Financial Stress in Emerging Market
Economies* https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/128519/1/ewp-356.pdf